# Can't start MySQL server on osX 10.11 - can't find PID file error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, osx-yosemite

Fisrt of all, you must know that I am a total newbie, non-coder, graphique designer that will be able to copy/paste any code but don't not assume that I can deduce any code/terminal command whatsoever please: I don't know the syntax.

So, here's my issue: I know there are plenty of issues on the web about this, even here, but all by myself I haven't been able to fix my poblem no matter how many thread I've read. I fear I'll need to be held by the hand through this.

I am trying to get a WordPress installation working locally on my Mac Book Pro running osX El Capitan 10.11. I tried following the instructions in that article: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/ .

It worked well untill I hit the MySQL section. Since I thought there was an issue with my root password (it ended out that the MySQL install had provided me a temporary pass that I forgot about), I tried uninstalling my MySQL install following these instructions: https://php-built.com/uninstall-mysql-from-os-x-yosemite/ , but after re-installing MySQL I kept getting this error: .. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/wks-000353.pid).

So, in a nutshell,

This:

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

... renders this:

.. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/wks-000353.pid)

This:

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -v

... renders this:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

And this:

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

... renders this:

ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

Help would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: As a first step, please check the access to the PID file. Do a "sudo ls -l /usr/local", then "sudo ls -l /usr/local/mysql", then "sudo ls -l /usr/local/mysql/data",  Maybe the directory doesn't exist, and you get "no such file or directory". That would explain why the starter can't get to the PID file.  Alternatively, if the directory is there, it might not be accessible by the user that is supposed to be running the database (usually user mysql or the like). In that case you'd have to open up the directory permissions to allow  access by the mysql user.

Comment: Hi Karel! First of all, thank you so much for this quick answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: "In that case you'd have to open up the directory permissions to allow access by the mysql user" How do I do that throught command line in the terminal?

Comment: Sorry my previous code paste didn't seem to work so here it is again: http://paste.ofcode.org/QFF9NX5ECp4RN3njz9TJZy

Comment: In order to try the perms for the mysql user: Do a "ps axu | grep mysqld" to find out the right username. Let's assume that the name is "mysql". Then, as root, run: "su mysql -c 'ls -l /usr'; su mysql -c 'ls -l /usr/local'; su mysql -c 'ls -l /usr/local/mysql'" and so on until you find the directory where the mysql user isn't allowed or you might see the PID file beloning to the wrong user. Note the single quotes around 'ls -l <dir>'. Good hunting!

Comment: Think I'll give up on that. I tried all the steps listed above as well as many others that I found online and I simply can't find out why that PID file can't be found or edited. All the directories and files related to MySQL seam to be wxr and the user seams to be mysql everywhere. Already spent too much time on this. su mysql commands do not work. Thanks anyway.